# MinGW and Windows 10

Tags: mingw, compatibility, windows-10

I am on the verge of utilizing my free upgrade to windows 10, but I am wondering if the C++ compiler through MinGW will still be compatible. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe; maybe not. MinGW is free software; no one is going to give you a warranty as to its fitness for any particular purpose, or to its suitability for deployment on any platform. It likely will work, but YMMV; your best bet is to try it, and see for yourself.

Comment: Windows 10 is still backward compatible with previous versions. Many of their customers run ancient applications whose authors, and sources, went missing long ago, so Microsoft can't afford to break backward compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the compiler is still compatbile because the Win32 API Interface didn't change. The Windows 10 UWP Platform is only an additional platform. Executables can be executed as they were executed in the past.